# Excel 2013 Function: INDIRECT.EXT add-in

Tags: search, microsoft-excel-2013, extension

I am using Excel 2013, and wanted to download Morefunc Addin, but can't get it to work. I need to use it to extract data from multiple cells in closed excel files. I understood with it added to excel, I could enter the following FUNCTION: =INDIRECT.EXT and it would allow me to specify a folder and a common cell(s) and sheet in all workbooks within the folder and it will return their values.

Comment: I am sure you can quote cells from other documents by typing "=" in the desired cell on the first excel document,opening the target document and select the cell there... I recall doing this before. It then puts a formula in the cell that says something like ='*documentname*.xlsx!: A1'. If you are having trouble with the extension why not try this? It can also be done within one Excel document per sheets too.

Comment: Are you sure that add-in is compatible with your Excel 2013? I saw a note on C|NET that states; *"Version 5 adds compatibility with Excel 2007. It still works in the 32-bit versions of Excel 2010 and 2013 but not in 64-bit versions."*

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my comment wasn't exactly correct, but I have found a link that can do this without extensions. [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell--range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f#bmintro)

you can type this =(['name of document'.xlsx]Sheet1!A1) to get the cell value of cell A1 in the workbook saved in a location that you choose after the formula is entered.

You can obviously change this to suit your needs per cell reference and sheet number/name.

Hope this helps